# How can I move 20 view definitions from one site to another?

Tags: web-part, list-view, migration

We developed a page with a number of webparts. Each webpart runs a different view. Now we're ready to put it in the test environment, but we can't figure out how to export the definitions so they can be imported into the test database.

We're very knew to SharePoint and are figuring things out as we go along. We tried to export a web-part and import it, but got an error message saying the list does not exist.

Before we spend a lot more time trying to figure this out:

1. What are the possible ways to export (powershell? designer?)
2. Can I export a list view definition to a place where I can edit it
   before I attempt to import it to the test site? (some of the column
   names my be different, and I'm thinking it might be easier to just edit them.)
3. Once we get this working in test and signed off by the user, what's
   the best way to migrate it to production?

Answer (score 0):

The way which we normally follow is via Site Backup and Restore.

This will be done first time. Then going forward the future releases are scripted using PowerShell.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. The views were developed in our development environment. There are some significant differences between the dev site and the test site, so I can't backup and restore.  I was really looking for  some way to export.